# Modifying y axis for combined plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to modify the y axis limit for this example given in ggplot2 wiki.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(1992, 2002, by=2)

d1 <- data.frame(x=x, y=rnorm(length(x)))
xy <- expand.grid(x=x, y=x)
d2 <- data.frame(x=xy$x, y=xy$y, z= jitter(xy$x + xy$y))

d1$panel <- "a"
d2$panel <- "b"
d1$z <- d1$x

d <- rbind(d1, d2)

p <- ggplot(data = d, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y))
p <- p + facet_grid(panel~., scale="free")
p <- p + layer(data= d1,  geom = c( "line"), stat = "identity")
p <- p + layer(data=d2, mapping=aes(colour=z, fill=z),  geom =
c("tile"), stat = "identity")
p
```

Is it possible to modify Y axis limits for panel "a" ? I want to change ymax = 1.5.

[image]

Comment: Faceting is good when you have the same sort of plot in each facet (based on Tufte's idea of small multiples). When you're combining different types of plots, you're much better of using `arrange.grid` so you can customize them individually.

Comment: This does not appear to be possible - see this thread [Specify xlim and ylim for each facet separately](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/187).

Comment: one idea could be to insert a value of 1.5 into the data, and mark so that the geom_line() doesn't catch it. I mean, to map it using other geom with color asthetic set to NA. this should do the trick, but it involves manual manipulation

Comment: You are faceting two different sets of data, for which `facet_wrap/grid` wasn't made for. I suggest you take @shujaa's advice about `grid.arrange` from `gridExtra` package. Here's a quote from @hadley from the link @shujaa provided that demonstrates why this is not possible in ggplot2: "you should be describing things in terms of the underlying data, not by some arbitrary panel number."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admonishments notwithstanding, it can be done without modifying the data.

Add a NA coloured geom (here, `geom_hline`) at the desired y value to panel "a" (that is, make sure the data frame is set to d1 for `geom_hline`). But I think the `grid.arrange` option would be neater.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(1992, 2002, by=2)
set.seed(17)
d1 <- data.frame(x=x, y=rnorm(length(x)))
xy <- expand.grid(x=x, y=x)
d2 <- data.frame(x=xy$x, y=xy$y, z= jitter(xy$x + xy$y))
d1$panel <- "a"
d2$panel <- "b"
d1$z <- d1$x
d <- rbind(d1, d2)

p <- ggplot(data = d, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y))
p <- p + facet_grid(panel~., scale="free")
p <- p + layer(data= d1,  geom = c( "line"), position = "identity", stat = "identity") + 
   geom_hline(data = d1, aes(yintercept = 1.5), colour = NA)

p <- p + layer(data=d2, mapping=aes(colour=z, fill=z),  geom =c("tile"), position = "identity", stat = "identity")
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(seq(-1.5, 1.5, .5), seq(1992, 2002, 2))) +
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1992, 2002, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this interesting answer. This will definitely help.